# VBA: saving to specific path based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I made a macro to save an Excel file on a location based on some cell values.
But when I run the macro the file won't save. 
The last line of the macro becomes yellow.

If I skip the **`dtMonth`** and **`dtMonthnumber`** the files saves just fine, so the problem is not **`dtYear`**, or **`Format(dtDate, "yymmdd")`**.

Do I need to concert the cell values?

The formulas in the cells are to convert date to month and year:

```
U1 =TEXT(Controle!H6;"mmmm")

U2 =TEXT(Controle!H6;"jjjj")

U3 =TEXT(H6;"mm")
```

```
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = Date

Dim dtMonth As String
Dim dtYear As String
Dim dtMonthnumber As String

dtMonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Controle").Range("U1")
dtYear = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Controle").Range("U2")
dtMonthnumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Controle").Range("U3")

Dim strFile As String
strFile = "M:\X-tra pakketten\" & dtYear & "\" & dtMonthnumber & " - " & dtMonth & "\" & Format(dtDate, "yymmdd") & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Does the folder exist? You must create the folder before trying to save a file to it.

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with the variables matching the folders then. Check in the `Locals` window that the `dtMonthnumber` and `dtMonth` variables (and ultimately the `strFile` string) exactly matches the folder path.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the folder did not exist. After creating the folder it ran perfect.  Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a VBA bug, where Breakpoints are sometimes not properly deleted. Try this:

1. Set a Breakpoint somewhere inside your procedure.
2. Change something inside your code, so it needs to recompile (for example add a `Debug.Print ""` somewhere)
3. Use the menu Debug > Delete all breakpoints (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)
4. Recompile it

That should solve the problem. If it still doesn't work, copy your code somewhere, delete the module, create a new module and insert the code again.

Comment: The problem was that the folder did not exist, but thanks for your suggestion.